# Copying the contents of one array to another in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I want to create 2 arrays, both size 5, and fill up the first one. Then I want to fill up the blank array with elements from the other one, but in reverse order. **The only check is I cannot use loops for this exercise, which is why, the size is set to a small number, in this case, 5.**

Right now, I am struggling with quite a few issues, but my code looks like this:

```
a DB 4, 72, 52, 12, 29
b DB 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ;I don't know how to define an empty array, so I am setting everything to zero

LEA SI, a[4]
MOV b[0], [SI]

LEA SI, a[3]
MOV b[1], [SI]

LEA SI, a[2]
MOV b[2], [SI]

LEA SI, a[1]
MOV b[3], [SI]

LEA SI, a[0]
MOV b[4], [SI]
```

So I am loading the addresses of each space in a from the reverse order, and moving that data to b. Is this the right solution?

Thanks.

Comment: In 8086 you cannot use two memory operands simultaneously in one instruction. You have to use an intermediate register. So change `LEA SI, a[4] --- MOV b[0], [SI]` to `MOV AL, a[4] --- MOV b[0], AL`.... and so on.

Comment: `rep movsb` would be one way, or just 2 word loads+stores and a byte load+store.  You don't need LEA.

Comment: @PeterCordes: How would you implement the reverse order with `rep movsb`? I guess this was a quick shot ;-)

Comment: @zx485 Could you write that down as an answer please? The comment formatting makes it a bit confusing.

Comment: @zx485: oh reverse.  That part of the problem was not in the title.  So yeah either byte loads into AL and AH, then word stores, or word loads + byte stores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 8086 assembly you cannot use two memory operands simultaneously in one instruction. You have to use an intermediate register and you also do not need to get the address first with the `LEA` instruction.

So, for example, change

```
LEA SI  , a[4]    ; get address of a[4]
MOV b[0], [SI]    ; invalid OpCodes -!!!-
```

to

```
MOV AL  , a[4]    ; mov a[4] to intermediate register AL
MOV b[0], AL      ; mov intermediate register AL to b[0]
```

...and so on for the other values.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is great. One extra question, can I actually declare an array of size 5 without storing any values initially? For instance, in my question, I am storing zeroes in array `b`, which seems less than ideal.

Comment: This depends on the assembler you are using. Your syntax seems to look like MASM/TASM, so try `b DB 5 dup(0)` which means: create an array with 5 BYTE values initially filled with the value `0`.

Comment: For Microsoft MASM, (ML.EXE), in segment _BSS or if using dot directive .data?, you could use `b db 5 dup (?)` , to allocate space for an uninitialized array.